# no version information available (required by /usr/bin/ssh)

Tags: linux, installation, debian, openssh, openssl

I am getting `no version information available` when making `ssh`.

Openssl verion:

```
sat:~# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Here is output of `ldd /usr/bin/ssh`:

```
/usr/bin/ssh: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/ssh)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff48bff000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fdd57f1f000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fdd57b3a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdd57935000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fdd5771e000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fdd57508000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fdd572c8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdd56f3e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdd583b3000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fdd56c6a000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fdd56a40000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fdd5683c000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fdd56633000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fdd5642e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdd56212000)
```

Output of `locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0`:

```
sat:~# locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/src/openssl-1.0.1f/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

How to fix this error?

Note:

I compiled and installed the `openssl`. After that, I installed `ssh` through `apt-get`.

Comment: I posted a solution to this problem in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830466/libcrypto-so-1-0-0-no-version-information-available-required-by-ssh/1198404#1198404).

Comment: I posted a solution to this problem in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830466/libcrypto-so-1-0-0-no-version-information-available-required-by-ssh/1198404#1198404).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I compiled and installed the openssl. After that, I installed ssh through apt-get.

These are probably two different versions of OpenSSL. You will probably be OK since 1.0.0 is binary compatible with 1.0.1, 1.0.2, etc (it won't be binary compatible with 1.1.0, however).

Your `ssh` is probably using the version of OpenSSL in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. You should use `LD_PRELOAD` to ensure your version of OpenSSL is being used (assuming binary compatibility, of course).

If you don't want to use `LD_PRELOAD` and friends, then build `ssh` from sources. Be sure to specify an `rpath` to ensure the link editor uses your version of OpenSSL, not he system's version. That is, your `LDFLAGS` should include something like `-Wl,-rpath,<path to your openssl>`. That's in addition to the customary `-lcrypto`, `-lssl` and `-L<path to your openssl>`.

If you are on Mac OS X, then be advised that linker options like `-Bstatic` and `-rpath` are silently ignored. You will encounter mysterious crashes due to incompatible binaries because OS X provide 0.9.8.

---

> no version information available

As for no version information, I have no idea. `ssh` can use either `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER` at compile time or `SSLeay`/`SSLeay_version` at runtime. See [`OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER.html) for details.

---

> How to fix this error?

Perhaps I'm misreading things, but I don't see an error anywhere in the post.

Answer (score 9):

Problem: `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` no version information available warning/error.

After much research, time and effort, (took weeks), here's what I finally ended up doing...

In the directory where you ended up extracting the source code for your version of openssl 1.0.1h (should work for other versions too.) I create a file called `openssl.ld`

In this file put this...

```
OPENSSL_1.0.0 {
    global:
    *;
};
```

save it.
Now type in...

```
make clean
```

(Just to be sure we are starting fresh.)

Now for the really mind boggling part...

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared -Wl,--version-script=openssl.ld -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Then...

```
make
make test
make install
ldconfig
```

And that should do it. 
(It's so simple. No patching required.)

I have applied this solution to Debian Wheezy both 32 and 64 bit versions. And have made an observation. The 64 bit version automatically defaults to the new `libssl.so.1.0.0` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` files that are created in the `/usr/local/lib` directory. The 32 bit version does not. Which is why I had thought at first that the 32 bit version of Debian Wheezy didn't suffer from this problem, but it does once you get the 32 bit version to use the new openssl libraries in the `/usr/local/lib` dir.

Using the `ldd` command to test what libraries the binaries are using was invaluable in figuring this out too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Here is an updated openssl.ld which handles 1.0.2 https://gist.github.com/Scottmitch/71a89d98b3af272aab6ae6bfed122c5a

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered that my above solution breaks certain binaries that require an OPENSSL_1.0.1 version. Like curl for example. apt-file search will no longer work with my solution as that uses curl. So some binaries want a 1.0.0 version and others want a 1.0.1 version.

I believe the solution lies in a editing of the openssl.ld file. So that some binaries will get the 1.0.0 version and other will get a 1.0.1 version. At the moment this is beyond me. Maybe somebody else can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install custom-compiled libraries, don't break your system by installing to prefixes `/usr/local`, `/usr` or `/`. Debian/Ubuntu, for example, will pick up custom libraries in `/usr/local/lib` the next time `ldconfig` is invoked because it's usually listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`.

Here's a throw-away box with openssl 1.0.2e `make install`'ed to `--prefix=/usr/local` and then run `ldconfig` (with no arguments, which updates `/etc/ld.so.cache`):

```
# ldconfig -p | egrep 'lib(crypt|ssl)'
libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so
libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libcrypto.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so
libcrypto.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
libcrypt.so.1 (libc6,x32, OS ABI: Linux 3.4.0) => /libx32/libcrypt.so.1
libcrypt.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
libcrypt.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /lib32/libcrypt.so.1
libcrypt.so (libc6,x32, OS ABI: Linux 3.4.0) => /usr/libx32/libcrypt.so
libcrypt.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so
libcrypt.so (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.24) => /usr/lib32/libcrypt.so
```

Notice how the custom-compiled ones override libs from the `openssl` package.

## Instead, the solution is to *vendor* custom libraries and binaries into isolated directories that are independent from the default ld.conf and PATH.

Install software to `/opt/$WHATEVER-$VERSION/`

Then, if you want to use custom-compiled binaries in `/opt/$WHATEVER-$VERSION/bin`, *append* that to the `PATH` (DO NOT PREPEND, because of the risk of breaking the system).

### For *static* linking $WHATEVER to something else

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/opt/$WHATEVER-$VERSION/include" \
   CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -I/opt/$WHATEVER-$VERSION/include" \
   LDFLAGS="-lwhatever -L/opt/$WHATEVER-$VERSION/lib"
```

### For *shared* linking $WHATEVER to something else

Same as above but add `-Wl,-rpath,/opt/$WHATEVER-$VERSION/lib` to LDFLAGS

Another thing to do is instead of `make install` use [`checkinstall`](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) to build a removable package where the full package name includes `custom-$WHATEVER-$VERSION` to allow easier version management to avoid breaking custom packages through incompatible upgrades.